# How do I type a backtick in RubyMine with a Swedish keyboard layout?

Tags: xorg, java, keyboard-layout

I am currently saddled with a [Swedish keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Swedish) at work (TMALSS: I left my nice [Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Japanese) one at home), which has some deadkeys, one of which is backtick.

I can type a backtick just fine in any application save [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) (and probably any stupid JVM app) either by pressing `S-Backtick S-Backtick` (i.e. pressing Backtick twice whilst holding down Shift), or by pressing `S-Backtick Space`.

Any clues what could be going on here? It almost certainly has to be Java, but I don't know anything about adjusting Java input settings or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the problem in RubyMine on natty.

If you still suffer from the problem, try the following work-around: change the *system* keyboard layout from `Keyboard Preferences > Layouts > Add` and pick `Country: Sweden` and `Variants: Sweden Eliminate dead keys`. That will give you the backtick by just pressing `S-Backtick`. If you need to change between the regular and eliminate dead keys layout variants, keep both available in layouts and set a convenient hot key to switch (in the `Layouts` tab click on `Options...` and then `Key(s) to change layout)`.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I had forgotten all about the option to eliminate dead keys. I blame xorg--when they made configuration so easy, I stopped having to look up keyboard layout names. ;)